# Sync iCloud TV show purchases between AppleTV and iTunes

Tags: itunes, icloud, data-transfer, appletv

**How do I sync AppleTV purchases from iCloud to iTunes?**

I recently purchased the most recent episode of Psych on my Apple TV but am unable to transfer it to iTunes.

I was able to do this with a previous episode but can't recall how.

I've tried going to `Store > Check for Available Downloads...` but it says I don't have anything to download:

[image]

I am using the same Apple Store account between the Apple TV and iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the iTunes store homepage and click "Purchased" in the Quick Links section. This will bring you to a list of all content that is available for redownload for your account.